# MS Access 2016 VBA Error "Invalid Operation" It is showing the error with the First IF statement in the second CASE

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Function Day1DU(InvFullBP As Single) As Single

Dim Current_Frm As Form
Set Current_Frm = Screen.ActiveForm
Dim CalcDuAdjs As Double, HBCO As Double, HBP As Double, AMRF As Double
```

Only my second time posting so please be nice.
I need to see if there is a value in the field FundDate of the SoldInfo_Tbl. If the field is blank then we need to assume 9/1/2020. If it is not null the it needs to be greater than 8/31/2020 to run the code.
I have never looked for a value this way. I have always referred to the current form.
Having issues with DAO.Database

ADVERSE MARKET REFINANCE FEE

```
Dim dbMyDB As DAO.Database
Dim tblSoldInfo As DAO.TableDef
Dim fldMyField As DAO.Field
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set dbMyDB = CurrentDb
Set tblSoldInfo = dbMyDB![SoldInfo_Tbl]
Set fldMyField = tblSoldInfo![FundDate]
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SoldInfo_Tbl", dbOpenTable)
```

ADVERSE MARKET REFINANCE FEE

```
Select Case Val(Current_Frm!InvestorID_Cbo.Column(0))
Case 2, 4, 15
    If Current_Frm!RateSheetDate_Txt > #8/12/2020# Then
      If Current_Frm!LoanType_Cbo <> "PURCHASE" And (Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "10" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "20" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "11" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "55" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "71" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "101" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "12" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "10H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "20H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "55H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "71H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "101H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "11H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "12H") Then
        AMRF = 0.5
      Else
        AMRF = 0
      End If
    End If
Case 16, 17
```

My issue below vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

```
    If Nz(rs![tblSoldInfo]![fldMyField], #9/1/2020#) > #8/31/2020# Then
      If Current_Frm!LoanType_Cbo <> "PURCHASE" And (Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "10" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "20" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "11" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "12" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "10H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "20H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "11H" Or Current_Frm!Plan_Cbo = "12H") Then
        AMRF = 0.5
      Else
        AMRF = 0
      End If
    End If
End Select
```

END ADVERSE MARKET refinance FEE

Comment: `rs![tblSoldInfo]![fldMyField]` is incorrect. You are accessing the recordset so you only need to provide the column name e.g. `rs![FieldName]`.

Comment: Also, you dont need to declare the TableDef and Field, just the recordset will do. If you need to update, open as `dbOpenDynaset` and update.

Comment: Thank you @Kostas K. for the help. I was having trouble so I kept adding on more. I got a little Google crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I have a split ms-access database. If the database is split the tables are not local and I can't use OpenRecordset("SoldInfo_Tbl", ***dbOpenTable***), I have to use ***dbOpenDynaset***.